# Vim Easytags Ctags error: "append mode is not compatible with tags to stdout"

Tags: vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

When I save a file in vim I get the following error:

```
easytags.vim 3.11: vim-misc 1.17.6: External command failed with exit code 1!
Command line: sh -c '(/usr/bin/ctags --fields=+l --c-kinds=+p --c++-kinds=+p --sort=no -f- '\''--language-force=vim'\'' '\''/home/nokan/.vimrc'\'') 1>'\''/tmp/v9KiWdN/18'\'' 2
>'\''/tmp/v9KiWdN/19'\'''

Output on standard output stream:
ctags: append mode is not compatible with tags to stdout (at function xolox#easytags#autoload[13]..xolox#easytags#update[31]..xolox#easytags#update#with_vim[4]..xolox#misc#os#
exec, line 163)
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be caused by having append mode enabled in your ~./ctags file. If you have the line `--append` try removing it.